# Forcing a function to end using SIGALRM in C

Tags: c, signals

Right now I have a function connected to `SIGARLM` that goes off after 1 second and will re-alarm itself to go off in another second everytime. There's a test in the logic of the `SIGALRM` function I wrote to see if a certain timeout has been reached and when it does I need it to kill a function that's running. Does anybody know how I can do this?

I forgot to mention: in the function that needs to be killed it waits on `scanf()` and the function needs to die even if `scanf()` hasn't returned yet.

Comment: Maybe add a flag in your to-be-killed function, and check if the flag is set, then return. Then obviously once you reach the timeout you need to set that flag.

Comment: made an edit. I have to find a way to terminate scanf() in the function to make it close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach that might be worth looking into is using [`select`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) to poll `stdin` and see if any data is ready.  `select` lets you wait for some period of time on a file descriptor, controlling when you can be interrupted and by what, and seems like it's perfect here.  You could just sit in a loop waiting for up to a second, then failing gracefully if no data is available.  That way, `SIGALRM` wouldn't need to kill the function; it would take care of that all by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're asking or what the structure of the program is.  If I understand correctly: some function is running and you want to terminate it if it's been running for X time.  You have a SIGALARM wake up every second and that will check the running time of the other function and do the terminate.

How do you plan to kill the function?  Is it a function in the same process, or is it a separate process.  Is your question how to terminate it or how to tell when it needs to be terminated?

I've done something which I believe is similar.  I had a multi-threaded application with a structure which contained information about the threads I wished to monitor.  The structure contained a member variable "startTime".  My monitoring (SIGALARM) function had access to a list of threads.  When the monitor woke up it would traverse the list, compare current time to each thread startTime and send a message to the function if it had exceeded it's allowed runtime.

Does this help at all?

Comment: The function is in the same process. Also, check out my edit. I have to work around scanf() running in the function that needs to be killed. This isn't a multi-threaded application.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a (global) variable to communicate between the signal handler and the function that should be stopped. The function then would check that variable to see if it should still continue running or if it should exit.

Something line this:

```
volatile int worker_expired = 0;

void worker() {
   while (!worker_expired) {
      // ...
   }
}

void sig_alrm() {
   worker_expired = 1;
}
```

Comment: I made an edit to the OP. The problem is this function that needs to die waits on scanf() and it needs to die at exactly at the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the signal to terminate IO operations, you need to make sure it's an **interrupting** signal handler. On modern systems, system calls interrupted by signals automatically restart unless you specify otherwise. Use the `sigaction` function rather than the `signal` function to setup your signal handlers if you want control over things like this. With `sigaction`, unless you specify `SA_RESTART`, signal handlers can interrupt.

If you're using file-descriptor IO functions like `read`, you should now get the effects you want.

If you're using `stdio` functions like `fscanf`, getting interrupted by a signal will put the `FILE` into an error state that can only be cleared by `clearerr`, and will lose any partial input in the buffer. Interrupting signals do not mix very well with `stdio` unless you just want to abort all operations on the file and close it when a signal is received.

Answer (score 0):

So ... to restate slightly: it isn't so much that you want to kill the function as that you want any pending i/o to terminate and the function to exit.

I would either:

1. use select() to periodically wake up and check a flag set by the signal handler.  if the flag isn't set and there's no input pending then loop and call select() again.
2. i suspect that your SIGALARM handler is doing more than just checking this one timer, and so using pselect() to check for i/o OR SIGALARM is probably not an option for you.  i wonder if you could grab a user defined signal, and pass that in pselect.  then your alarm handler would send that user defined signal.

Regarding choice 1, if SIGALARM is waking every second then you can adjust the time that select() sleeps to be within your maximum error latency.  In other words assume that the timeout occurs immediately after the call to select(), then it will take until select() wakes up to detect the flag set by the SIGALARM handler.  So if select() wakes up 10 times per second then it could take up to 1/10 second to detect the setting of the "give up" flag (set by the SIGALARM handler).